# How can I connect a CW keyer to my Mac and transmit CW on VHF?

Tags: cw, vhf

I currently have a Kenwood TM-V71A 2m/70cm transceiver that I would like to connect to my Macbook to transmit morse code, using the cocoaModem software. Aside from the cables needed to connect the radio to the Macbook and possibly an external USB sound card, I'm wondering what I need in order to connect a CW keyer to the computer. I don't want to generate CW with the computer, I just want to transmit CW myself with a keyer such as the MFJ 564 iambic dual paddle. Most 2m radios (mine included) do not have a jack into which you can plug a CW keyer, thus my need to connect through the computer.

From what I understand, the paddle does not generate a tone by itself, and it seems to connect through a 1/4" phone plug. Would I need to build my own tone generator circuit that is controlled by the keyer and outputs audio into the microphone jack of the computer? Or would I be able to generate a tone from software and plug the keyer directly into the microphone jack? I'd prefer to buy a tone generator circuit (if one is needed), but I'm not opposed to building one myself from a kit.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: The other question only applies to Windows as far as software goes, but does refer to 'code practice oscillators', which I think is what I need in order to connect the keyer to the microphone jack and generate an audible tone.

Comment: ↑ I think that's pretty much the same question and the answers cover various methods and mention some software.

Comment: (Some specifics: you're right that if you use an oscillator that'll get you an audible tone. You'll want to hook it to a _line-level_ input, as any CPO not built for the purpose is going to have a output too “hot” for a mic input. And I see the TM-V71A is a FM rig, so a tone is what you want to feed to the rig anyway (MCW) since it can't transmit or receive true CW. You don't actually need any software at all at that point. You'd be using software if you took one of the other options mentioned there like connecting the keyer to a serial port.)